# No IPv6 loopback address in Ubuntu container

Tags: networking, docker, ipv6

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 VM running via VirtualBox on my MacBook.  `ip addr` shows (among other things):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Within this VM, I ran

```bash
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:22.04 bash
```

Inside the container, I installed `net-tools` and ran `ifconfig`.  The output contained

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Why is there no IPv6 loopback address in the container when there is one in the host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker default settings don't enable IPv6 support. Add the following to your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
    "ipv6": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd01::/16", // whatever subnet you want to use
    "ip6tables": true
}
```

Reload the `docker` service configuration using your service manager afterwards.